# <base> tag is working in my localhost but not in my website

Tags: html, base-url

```
<base href="//localhost/virsan/" />
<link href="assets/stylesheets/font.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I am using base tag like `<base href="//localhost/virsan/" />` in my localhost.

In domain I am using it like `<base href="virsa.ca/" />`, but it's not working.

When I use it online it gives me error page 404 URL like `http://virsa.ca/collection/neckwear/8/`.

Comment: first base <base href="//localhost/virsan/" /> i am using it on appache on my local computer 
but when i put it online it gives me error

Comment: Is the base really necessary if it's just the URL root path? I'm thinking the 404 error is not because of the base.

Comment: base is necessary i am using function

function news_link($id, $title) {
$slug = $title;
return "collection/$slug/$id/";

}
 for my url

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<base href="http://virsa.ca/" />
```

You need to specify full url

Comment: @user3682988 look the css path http://virsa.ca/assets/stylesheets/font.css . Its loaded

Comment: sir i am trying to change the url in php it change the url but page not found

Comment: i change my url collection.php?id=8&slug=neckwear to collection/neckwear/8/

Comment: @user3682988 the problem is that an index.php file in your url. please see http://virsa.ca/index.php/collection/neckwear/8/ this, to do this you need to sepecify the index.php in your path. the base url will be, http://virsa.ca/index.php/

Comment: index.php is different page and collection.php is different page m trying to rewrite the url :P

Answer (score 0):

try checking the console from your browser which asset are missing and for what reason.
and one thing i recommend is to check if the problem comes from the base tag. by avoiding using base tag and loading resources using their fully qualified address.